# Docker SSH or Detach/Attach

Tags: docker

I have a [docker image](https://github.com/biwa7636/docker_scrapy) with all the necessary tools and environment properly set up. However, I am having a hard time running it in the background.

Seems like there are two approaches:

(1) can run the box as daemon and I can attach to it whenever I want to use the box. However, the container exit with code zero right after I run it as daemon.

```
$:~/docker/docker_scrapy$ sudo docker run -ti -v ~/docker/docker_scrapy/myvolume:/var/myvolume 3fb9894af1d9 /bin/bash
root@3fc39116a586:/# python -c 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup'
root@3fc39116a586:/# cd /var/myvolume/
root@3fc39116a586:/var/myvolume# 

$:~/docker/docker_scrapy$ sudo docker run -d -v ~/docker/docker_scrapy/myvolume:/var/myvolume 3fb9894af1d9
c5fab6e6ac02a579e3371aa641b18ca67feb93a9f4f4934b6d083157182fe4e1
$:~/docker/docker_scrapy$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Clearly, I can start the box in the interactive mode, but when I try to run it as a daemon, it will exit with code 0 right after I started. And I can not attach to it because I need to start it. Does that mean you can not run a image in the daemon mode if it is idle?

(2 )Or setting it up as a SSH server, and I can ssh in and do the work whenever I want. Like Vagrant up/ssh..

In summary:

(1) What did I do wrong with the detach/attach?

(2) Which is the proper way to have a run docker in the background? daemon/ssh

Comment: could you include the actual command run when you start the container in the background?

Comment: I have a similar problem trying to run Oracle db (which runs as a service) inside a container. When I run with *-it* it works fine; when I use *-d* it exits, as soon as the entrypoint script reaches EOF. It seems Docker kind of sucks at running daemonized processes (among other things) in daemonized container mode...

Answer (score 3):

If you give it another command to run after starting the service that waits for input then the container will keep running until you attach and exit *that* command. I usually leave a shell running after the service starts so I can debug things. here's a simple example:

First let's create a service that runs in the background

```
arthur@a:~$ docker run -ti  ubuntu bash
root@5dc7f330b947:/# cat <<'EOF' >start-service.sh
> while true
> do
>   echo service is running >> service.log
>   sleep 10
> done 
> EOF
root@5dc7f330b947:/# chmod +x start-service.sh 
root@5dc7f330b947:/# exit
arthur@a:~$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
5dc7f330b947        ubuntu:12.04        bash                50 seconds ago      Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                       jolly_nobel         
arthur@a:~$ docker commit 5dc7f330b947 service/example
4c37b69b129287d79a6fe3916e4293f935194966b1de49d125f1cf8d6ab14f6f
```

then we can start it (i background it with a & here. in your example the & would not be required). Note it's fine to use both the interactive and detach options.

```
arthur@a:~$ docker run -ti -d service/example  bash -c "./start-service.sh & bash"
b35a5397ea2d29b4085d93ef32270379b09e49118380b0376309bca74fd719d0
arthur@a:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b35a5397ea2d        service/example:latest   bash -c './start-ser   7 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds                            cranky_wright
```

later we can attach and check on the service by looking in it's log file:

```
arthur@a:~$ docker attach b35a5397ea2d

root@b35a5397ea2d:/# cat service.log 
service is running
service is running
service is running
root@b35a5397ea2d:/#
```

I don't recommend running sshd inside the container because it leaves an option for attackers that isn't strictly useful for me.

Comment: +1 Can you please explain the meaning of the first `bash` in `docker run -ti -d service/example  bash -c "./start-service.sh & bash"`. Is it a `COMMAND` in terms of the [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) syntax? I am currently trying `docker run -ti -d service/example bash -c bash` (for allowing `ssh` into a detached container) and wonder if one `bash` may be redundant.

Comment: Yes the second bash is redundant. The -c is an argument to the program bash rather than an argument to the program named docker. bash -c "command line here" starts the bash shell/program and instructs it to run whatever comes after the -c as of you typed it at the command prompt. New versions of docker will insert calls to bash -c  automatically in many cases which is helpful, and makes it unclear where you actually need such things

Answer (score 0):

A lots of questions in there.  I would firstly suggest you go through the docker tutorial to grasp some of the underlying concepts.   That said...

That Dockerfile will never run in the background, that's not how docker works.   There is no cmd, no entrypoint, nothing to run.

Docker by default runs one task, when that returns the container stops.  So if all you wanted was a sshd you would run that as your CMD in non daemon mode.  (sshd -D)

There are ways to run daemonized apps though:

Using supervisord, as documented on the [docker site](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/).

Another alternative is [phusion/baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker).

Phusion/baseimage provides ssh access, but honestly to do what I need in containers I find [nsenter](https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter) easier to use.    Especially when paired with the phusion docker-bash tool.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice**: this answer promotes a tool I've written.

First of all, conceptually running multiple processes in one container is not the right approach (https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/). A more favorable solution is one that involves multiple containers each running their own process/service. Linking them together would result in a coherent application.

I've created a containerized SSH server that you can 'stick' to any running container. This way you can create compositions with every container, without that container even knowing about ssh. The only requirement is that the container has bash.

The following example would start an SSH server attached to a container with name 'sshd-web-server1'.

```
docker run -ti --name sshd-web-server1 -e CONTAINER=web-server1 -p 2222:22 \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh
```

You connect to the SSH server with your ssh client of choice, just as you normally would.

Be adviced: Docker-SSH is currently still under development, but it does work! Please let me know what you think

For more pointers and documentation see: https://github.com/jeroenpeeters/docker-ssh